# Magneto 2 custom console command undefined nanespace

Tags: console, command, magento2

I have to implement a custom cli command. I started from scratch by a step by step tutorial. I have copy-paste everything, but the message is:
"There are no commands defined in the "bss:checkcli" namespace.".

Of course I have cleared and rebuilt the cache.

The mentioned tutorial: https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-create-console-command-magento2/

I am new to console development so I have no idea what do I step next.

Any idea?

Comment: have you run this command php bin/magento bss:checkcli:custom?

Comment: When I am running this command "php bin/magento bss:checkcli:custom test" I am getting perfect output

Comment: Yes I tried exactly what you did. Now I ran with the test option and the error was the same

Comment: please attach screen shot of folder structure of it.

Comment: Here you are: http://7260.s.t4vps.eu/magento2-folder-structure.png

Comment: thx Jinesh for your afford. I installed magento2 freshly and copy-paste from that tutor so I am really puzzled right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209304/discussion-between-jinesh-and-szatti1489).